# printing and writing Unicode characters in Python

Tags: python, unicode, python-unicode

I am trying to get some Unicode characters printed out or written to a text file and am running into Errors..please advice, trying to google gave me a few hints but that error ed too..below is my code..What might I be doing wrong here..

I am trying to eventually use 'requests' and parse JSON with data that has Unicode values..

I am trying to parse JSON using requests from this url

https://api.discogs.com/releases/7828220

```
try:
        import requests
import json
url = 'https://api.discogs.com/releases/7828220'
headers = { 'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.0; WOW64; rv:24.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/24.0' }
art = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
json_object = json.loads(art.text)
try:
    print str(json_object['companies'][0][name])
except:
    print "Genre list isn't defined"

    {u'name': u'\u041e\u041e\u041e "\u041f\u0430\u0440\u0430\u0434\u0438\u0437"', u'entity_type': u'10', u'catno': u'PARAD-432', u'resource_url': u'https://api.discogs.com/labels/210403', u'id': 210403, u'entity_type_name': u'Manufactured By'}
```

Here json_object['companies'][0][name] has a few Unicode characters that wont display on the command line terminal and also wont write to a file with the required output (Unicode)

```
Actual output looks like "ООО "Парадиз"",
```

how can I get python to interpret these values as it appears?

Comment: what is the error? what is the question?

Comment: By the way bytes = u'' is already an unicode string

Comment: Are you sure that your terminal font supports those missing characters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> won't display on the command line terminal

What errors do you get?  In any event, the following works if you remove the unnecessary `str()` conversion and quote `'name'` on a terminal that supports UTF-8, such as Linux:

```
import requests
import json

url = 'https://api.discogs.com/releases/7828220'
headers = { 'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.0; WOW64; rv:24.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/24.0' }
art = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
json_object = json.loads(art.text)
print json_object['companies'][0]['name']
```

Output:

```
ООО "Парадиз"
```

On Windows, the command console may not default to an encoding that supports the characters you are trying to print.  One easy way is to switch to a supported encoding, in this case `chcp 1251` changes the code page to one supporting Russian, and will make the above work.

to write it to a file, use `io.open` with an encoding:

```
import io
with io.open('output.txt','w',encoding='utf8') as f:
    f.write(json_object['companies'][0]['name'])
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explaination, I am using Windows 10 and the command line terminal isnt supporting the fonts, but I was wondering why it wouldnt write to a file with those russian characters, but with the code you showed, it works! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your "bytes" is already unicode, so there should be no error.

```
>>> bytes = u'\xd0\x9e\xd0\x9e\xd0\x9e"\xd0\x9f\xd0\xb0\xd1\x80\xd0\xb0\xd0\xb4\xd0\xb8\xd0\xb7"'
>>> print unicode(bytes) 
ÐÐÐ "ÐÐ°ÑÐ°Ð´Ð¸Ð·"
```

However, if you are converting a python2 string / bytestring (without a `u""` prefix) to unicode, the default encoding is ascii.

```
>>> bytes = '\xd0\x9e\xd0\x9e\xd0\x9e"\xd0\x9f\xd0\xb0\xd1\x80\xd0\xb0\xd0\xb4\xd0\xb8\xd0\xb7"'
>>> print unicode(bytes)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xd0 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

The correct encoding to use here is UTF8. You can tell `unicode()` which encoding to use.

```
>>> print unicode(bytes, 'utf8')
ООО "Парадиз"
```

Comment: Unicode is handled in a much more sensible way in python 3. If you are new to python, I highly recommend using that instead of python 2.

Comment: I would recommend that even if you are not new to python